# Lubuntu nm-applet wifi icon missing

Tags: wireless, 14.04, lubuntu, network-manager, icons

I have a Lubuntu (now 14.04) installation. Recently, I logged in to find that the Wi-Fi icon had disappeared, and there was some sort of a keyboard icon in it's place. I have restarted multiple times, but it doesn't fix it. I can't find the same applet in the panel settings, and resetting the panel didn't help. When I try to manually start `nm-applet`, it starts, but prints a bunch of warnings to the console:

```
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

It then starts, using ugly icons for the Wi-Fi connectivity symbol.

What do I need to do to make it start correctly? Once it starts, why isn't it using the right icons?

Comment: Same problem for me.
Besides the network manager icon doesn't appear even typing "nm-applet" under "Manual autostarted applications" as suggested...
And this is a bug reported a lot of times in the past to Lubuntu developers...

Comment: @pigeonkiller The problem turned out to be a Trusty glitch. See here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu#Applications

Comment: [Bug #1308348 - lxsession network settings indicator missing from panel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1308348)

Comment: [Bug #1302462 - xfce4-panel network icon disappeared in xubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-panel/+bug/1302462)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fix the Network Manager not showing up on the panel issue, from the Lubuntu menu select Preferences > Default applications for LXSession, then click on the Autostart tab and under "Manual autostarted applications" type "nm-applet", then click the "+ Add" button on the left:

Now log out, log back in and you should see the Network Manager icon on the panel:
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about that, but if it's not working, isn't that just a patch, and not a fix? I think the problem isn't that it's not being run, but that it's failing and exiting when it's run. What normally runs it? Is it just listed in the startup list?

Comment: What does this command tell you? `ps aux | grep nm-apple` that will let you know if it is running, but what I posted in my answer is a fix to a bug issue with lubuntu 14.04 where nm-applet does not show in the panel

Comment: OK... is this really a problem with Trusty? I had assumed I screwed something up. I'll test this as soon as it finishes what it's installing.

Comment: I just tested this, and it got it to show up. But the icon still looks wrong; why can't it find the right icons?

Comment: It may be because of the bug or did you do an upgrade instead of a fresh install? I really do not have a fix for that, I am glad it is showing up now, please accept the answer to help other people since the icon is no longer missing. I suggest starting a new question just for the ugly icon issue. Thanks

Comment: Even if you run Lubuntu with a simple window manager (Blackbox in my case) which doesn't have an applet toolbar, you only need to run nm-applet once (in LXDE) and connect to your network. On subsequent reboots you will be connected automatically.

Comment: None of this works for Gnome-Shell.

Comment: Never said it did, it is for a bug in lubuntu about 9 months ago.

Comment: @WildMan What theme is this?

Comment: @RjQuery , I do not know, karel edited that answer so it is his theme.

Comment: @karel What theme is this?

Comment: @RjQuery It's LXDE with Lubuntu-default theme like [this Lubuntu 14.04 screenshot](http://ubuntuportal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/lubuntu-14-04-customize-look-and-feel.jpg)

Comment: @WildMan how does it work in Ubuntu 20_04 with `lxqt`? `nm-applet` works, but the gui solution..

Comment: @Timo, I have not used lubuntu in quite sometime so I asked a friend of mine that is heavily involved with lubuntu and he said that it does not apply past  18.04/LXDE, this is the friend. https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc

Comment: lxnm (lxnm-applet) is LXDE so last used in 18.04 by Lubuntu. LXQt used by 18.10 & later is very similar yes but expect it to be different (a lot of LXDE devs joined with RazorQt creating the LXQt project). In 20.04 it's `nm-tray` (which will call `nm-connection-editor` from network-manager-gnome as it's a little more user-friendly than the LXQt one used in 18.10-19.10).   Thanks @WildMan

Comment: @guiverc you're welcome and thanks for looking at this comment and replying.