# wireless bcm4318 not working

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom

Edit: I researched also link suggested above - it is option (3) And indeed is very helpful. Especially @LuisAlvarado's answer - it contains table which suggest using **linux-firmware-nonfree** - I tried and it did not worked (possibly because my system was polluted by remnants of previous attempts). Instead, **b43-fwcutter** from option (2) after clean reinstall worked for me. Linked answer contains good explanation of the process, but advice about exact module to use might be incorrect. wileress.kernel.org has different value value, which worked for me.

Original post:

I cannot get bcm4318 working on Lubuntu 14.4. 
This card worked on lubuntu 12.10 but upgrading failed, and after full reinstall from liveUSB I cannot get wifi to work. I tried these suggestions:

- (1) [Advice for 12.4](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) suggests to `apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source`
- (2)  [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29) says: `apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`instead, says: `apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer` but did not work either.
- (3) [This suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) `apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` - well worth reading, excellent explanation of problem.

Every time I purged packages from previous try and rebooted afterwards.

- (4)  [This also suggest blacklisting some entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). It seems that b43 from (2) should work (bcm43xx entry is blacklisted). But no luck.
- (5) Downgrading is also suggested by [this year-old answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286734/how-to-downgrade-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcmwl-kernel-source) but I was hoping there is something newer/better. The author claims that every release makes bcm43xx harder.

What else I should try?

I checked "ultimate authority" on bcm43xx wireless, http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices which says (in debian section) to use option (2), but no luck.

By "no luck" I mean that `iwconfig` says `no wireless connection`.
In my office I have wired connection to modem but no apparent wireless.
Is `iwconfig` a right way to test if my wireless is alive?

`lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl`:

```
b43                   356470  0   
bcma                   42043  1 b43  
mac80211              545990  1 b43  
cfg80211              409394  2 b43,mac80211  
ssb                    51854  2 b43,b44
```

`lspci -nn | grep 0280`

```
06:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g]   802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
```

`uname -mr`

```
3.13.0-24-generic i686
```

My laptop is Acer Aspire 5610Z with 0.5GB of RAM which I am going to upgrade to 4GB ASAP.

---

I got it working.

Correct answer is option (2), at least for my combinations of whatever is relevant.

What probably caused my earlier problems was that I was installing using synaptic gui. When I did install using terminal and apt-get, I noticed that `apt-get update` complained about duplicate sources. Once resolved, I again went over whole installing exercise, including fresh reinstall (to make sure there are no remnants of other installs), and straight to option (2) as suggested by wireless.kernel.org.

Regarding other options, it is above my paygrade to decide if they are invalid and need to be updated, or can stay as is, if approaches suggested by (1) and (3) are correct and may work for someone else.

Comment: What driver is in place now? lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl What is your exact card? lspci -nn | grep 0280 Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: Try simply get into Settings -> software sources -> last tab -> select proprietary driver for that Broadcom.

Comment: I tried that first but I have no entries to select from. Do I need to enable some special repositories?

Comment: I believe you have the correct driver for your device. Is this your problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/451593/lubuntu-nm-applet-wifi-icon-missing

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why? Supposed duplicate does **not** answer my question, I tried it and mentioned in my research. I did what wireless.kernel.org said I should do, it worked, not sure why I my post was downvoted. Oh well, ife is too short to deal with such crap. Thank you for nothing.

Comment: @PeterMasiar Hi, for the down vote I guess someone takes down voting to serious. I have upvoted you since this type of question do not deserve a downvote. For the correct installation, you are saying you did #2 which is "firmware-b43-installer", is this correct? I would also ask if you edited any config files previous to installing this specific driver or in general have a 100% clean ubuntu install before proceeding to install the driver mentioned, this is because some installations leave config files behind that may affect how other similar drivers work.

Comment: I did #2 after clear reinstall. I read many posts (including very helpful yours) about removal/blacklist some sources, I thought that new clean reinstall would be the simplest option for me, so I don't have to worry is `purge` removed all configs cleanly. It is entirely possible that `linux-firmware-nonfree` (option #3 as mentioned in table from @LuisAlvarado answer) installs same underlying code as `firmware-b43-installer` from option #2 and wireless.kernel.org. And if I just happened to use #3 before #2, I would have same results.

Comment: I am not expert, installing ubuntu every 2 years is enough for me :-) I just wanted to pinpoint the discrepancies.

Comment: Don't worry, I ask because every once in a while a very special case appears, like yours. I will open the question and you can add the specific answer to this particular case. Thanks for the feedback in tracking all possible cases. I have added your case (4318 Rev2) to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

Correct answer is option (2), at least for my combinations of whatever is relevant.

What probably caused my earlier problems was that I was installing using synaptic gui. When I did install using terminal and apt-get, I noticed that `apt-get update` complained about duplicate sources. Once resolved, I again went over whole installing exercise, including fresh reinstall (to make sure there are no remnants of other installs), and straight to option (2) as suggested by wireless.kernel.org.

Regarding other options, it is above my paygrade to decide if they are invalid and need to be updated, or can stay as is, if approaches suggested by (1) and (3) are correct and may work for someone else.

Comment: Hi Peter, please update the answer so it does not look like a comment but an actual answer, something like "I read the whole broadcom answer by Luis alvarado & Chili555 and it sucked, so I made a better one about the BCM4318 rev2 correct driver"... or something to that effect ^^.

Answer (score 3):

Option number 2 worked for me. I had originally installed the bcmwl kernel source through the additional drivers gui. I later installed the b43w cutter and installer with no luck.  After the bcmwl purge and b43w cutter reinstall it took off working. Thanks a bunch!

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install --reinstall b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot. Enjoy Ubuntu!

Answer (score -1):

> Ahhh! After a day of confusion and following simalar steps I went into software and updates and let it load (Note:this may take some time) and checked Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (propietary)

Also do note that Alt may take place of Fn in some cases

This may help:
[http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt ]